# Could not connect to database on GoDaddy Wordpress basic

Tags: wordpress, godaddy-api

I purchased GoDaddy Wordpress basic and it was working fine
I made a reset using WP Reset Plugin because I wanted to start designing all over again
Afterwards everytime I want to access Wordpress I have this error message
[image: Error]